# Getting facebook friends checkin using Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I'd like to query for my facebook friend's check-ins using Foursquare. Is this possible  and how can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't see check-ins of anybody unless you are friends with them on Foursquare first (regardless if you're friends with them on Facebook). But if they are your friends on Foursquare, you should be able to see users' check-ins via [checkins/recent](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/recent) or [users/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins)